# Is there a web page where Microsoft keeps an up-to-date list of C++11 features implemented in the most recent VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Is there a web page where Microsoft keeps an up-to-date list of C++11 features implemented in the most recent version of VC++ (including compiler updates like the one in November 2012) ?

I am mostly interested in VS2012 and VC++11.

Comment: I'm not aware of an official page nor one that is kept up to date.  Stephan Lavavej sometimes posts on the VCBlog about standards support for compiler and library, such as this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx  But as far as I know, there's no offical page with that kind of detailed content.

Answer (score 3):

A Google search yielded a table in MSDN that lists C++11 core language features and their implementation status in both Visual C++ 2010 and Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2012: [this document describes the features of the new C++ Standard—also known as C++11—that are implemented in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx).  The comment section of that article has a link to the page with the updated table referred to in the comments by @michael-burr [C++11 Features in Visual C++ 11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx)

Comment: Nice link - this question should be reopened. I have no idea how this could be considered unhelpful to future visitors.